# Comparing strings in onPostExecute (resulting from mysql operation)

Tags: java, android, mysql, string, android-asynctask

I have been trying to connect to a mysql database and it was succesfull. In the onPostExecute method, I get a result which seems to me exactly the same as the real input. In this example the emailadress jb@jb.jb. Logcat shows both the real input as the result. Yet my code doesn't agree that it is the same. Any advice?

EDIT: This link apparently gave the answer: [answer on the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

[image: Code]
[image: Logcat output]

Comment: use `.equals` instead of `==`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion

Comment: used `if(result.equals(username))`

Comment: And it's working. Thanks guys. tried the '==' with hardcoded strings and it worked but apparently my real code needs the 'equals' method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `String.equals()` instead of `==` to compare `Strings`. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)